# How to pass constructor parameters when using boost::di for making singleton

Tags: c++, boost, dependency-injection

I am new to dependency injection frameworks.
In the following code when I try to make the Child object as singleton, it gives errors and does not compile (see code below).

```
    In file included from /root/Projects/CLionProjects/Experiment/DI/main.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/boost/di.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::aux::concept_check<boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::concepts::scope<Child>::requires_<boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::concepts::scope<boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::_, boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::_>::is_referable, boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::concepts::scope<boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::_, boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::_>::try_create, boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::concepts::scope<boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::_, boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::_>::create> >’:
/usr/local/include/boost/di.hpp:1710:71:   required by substitution of ‘template<class T, typename boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::aux::concept_check<typename boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::concepts::scopable__<T>::type>::type <anonymous> > auto boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::core::dependency<boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::scopes::deduce, Child, Child, boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::no_name, void, boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::core::pool<boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::aux::type_list<boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::core::ctor_arg<Child, 0, int&>, boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::core::ctor_arg<Child, 1, double> > > >::in<T, <anonymous> >(const T&) [with T = Child; typename boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::aux::concept_check<typename boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::concepts::scopable__<T>::type>::type <anonymous> = <missing>]’
/root/Projects/CLionProjects/Experiment/DI/main.cpp:118:68:   required from here
/usr/local/include/boost/di.hpp:379:20: error: static assertion failed: constraint not satisfied
  379 |   static_assert(T::value, "constraint not satisfied");
      |                    ^~~~~
/root/Projects/CLionProjects/Experiment/DI/main.cpp: In function ‘auto Singleton::retObjChild()’:
/root/Projects/CLionProjects/Experiment/DI/main.cpp:118:68: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::core::dependency<boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::scopes::deduce, Child, Child, boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::no_name, void, boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::core::pool<boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::aux::type_list<boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::core::ctor_arg<Child, 0, int&>, boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::core::ctor_arg<Child, 1, double> > > >::in<Child>(const boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::scopes::singleton&)’
  118 |         auto secondVariable = firstVariable.in<Child>(di::singleton);
      |                                                                    ^
In file included from /root/Projects/CLionProjects/Experiment/DI/main.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/boost/di.hpp:1711:8: note: candidate: ‘template<class T, typename boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::aux::concept_check<typename boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::concepts::scopable__<T>::type>::type <anonymous> > auto boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::core::dependency< <template-parameter-1-1>, TExpected, <template-parameter-1-3>, <template-parameter-1-4>, <template-parameter-1-5>, <template-parameter-1-6> >::in(const T&) [with T = T; typename boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::aux::concept_check<typename boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::concepts::scopable__<T>::type>::type <anonymous> = <anonymous>; TScope = boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::scopes::deduce; TExpected = Child; TGiven = Child; TName = boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::no_name; TPriority = void; TCtor = boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::core::pool<boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::aux::type_list<boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::core::ctor_arg<Child, 0, int&>, boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::core::ctor_arg<Child, 1, double> > >]’
 1711 |   auto in(const T&)noexcept {
      |        ^~
/usr/local/include/boost/di.hpp:1711:8: note:   substitution of deduced template arguments resulted in errors seen above
/root/Projects/CLionProjects/Experiment/DI/main.cpp:121:37: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
  121 |         return injector.create<Child>();
      |                                     ^
/root/Projects/CLionProjects/Experiment/DI/main.cpp:121:39: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
  121 |         return injector.create<Child>();
```

But If I do not use singleton, code works correctly (see code below).
What wrong am I doing in this code? Please explain.

Also If I do not pass parameters, I can create Singleton correctly.

```
#include "boost/di.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
using namespace chrono_literals;

class Base
{
    int k;

    protected:
        Base(int param) : k{param}{}

        virtual void printFields()
        {
            cout << "k = " << k << endl;
        }
};

class Child final : public Base
{
    double j;

    public:
        Child(int param, double d) : Base(param), j {d} {}

        void printFields() override
        {
            cout << "j = " << j << endl;
            Base::printFields();
        }
};

int globalK = 0;

void setGlobalK()
{
    int count{};
    while(count++ < 2)
    {
        this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    }
    globalK = 100;
}

namespace Singleton
{
    auto retObjChild()
    {
        while(globalK != 100) this_thread::sleep_for(1s);

        // Trying to make it singleton is not working,
        // auto injector = di::make_injector(di::bind<Child>.to<Child>(globalK, 5.6).in<Child>(di::singleton));

        // But this works
        // auto injector = di::make_injector(di::bind<Child>.to<Child>(globalK, 5.6));

        // Zig Razor's suggestion (does not work). Content updated to reflect Error in following code
        auto firstVariable = di::bind<Child>.to<Child>(globalK, 5.6);
        auto secondVariable = firstVariable.in<Child>(di::singleton);
        auto injector = di::make_injector(secondVariable);
        return injector.create<Child>();
    }
}

int main()
{
    thread t{setGlobalK};
    Singleton::retObjChild().printFields();
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `gives errors and does not compile` - what error?

Comment: please add the compilation error.

Comment: @ZigRazor Raffallo Updated the errors

Comment: There is no di library in boost.

Comment: @user7860670 yah, I think it's a part of [boost external](https://github.com/boost-ext), whatever that is